# How to save images to a folder from web scraping? (Python)

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, directory

How do I make it so that each image I garnered from web scraping is then stored to a folder? I use Google Colab currently since I am just practicing stuff. I want to store them in my Google Drive folder.

This is my code for web scraping:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def getdata(url):
  r = requests.get(url)
  return r.text

htmldata = getdata('https://www.yahoo.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

imgdata = []
for i in soup.find_all('img'):
  imgdata = i['src']
  print(imgdata)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a pics folder manually in the folder where the script is running to store the pictures in it. Than i changed your code in the for loop so its appending urls to the `imgdata` list. The `try except`block is there because not every url in the list is valid.

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

htmldata = getdata('https://www.yahoo.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

imgdata = []
for i in soup.find_all('img'):
    imgdata.append(i['src']) # made a change here so its appendig to the list
    


filename = "pics/picture{}.jpg"
for i in range(len(imgdata)):
    print(f"img {i+1} / {len(imgdata)+1}")
    # try block because not everything in the imgdata list is a valid url
    try:
        r = requests.get(imgdata[i], stream=True)
        with open(filename.format(i), "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    except:
        print("Url is not an valid")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.write('whatever')
foo.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.